# Assignment problem with unique "unemployment" costs

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

Given $w$ workers and $k < w$ tasks, the usual integer cost matrix $(c_{ij})$ for the cost of assigning worker $i$ to task $j$ and a cost vector $(u_p)$ which assigns **any selection** $p$ of unassigned workers a unique unassignment cost.

We search for a minimum cost assignment where the cost includes the $u_p$ and $p$ is the vector containing all unassigned workers.

Can this problem be reformulated as an equivalent classical linear assignment problem? I.e. is there a way to model the requirement that when a worker is assigned to a task, **all** the combinations $p$ containing that worker may not occur in the result?

Here is a simple example: Suppose workers $a,b,c,d$ and tasks $x,y$. Assigning $a$ to $x$ and $b$ to $y$ has cost $1$, any other assignment has cost $2$. $c$ and $d$ are both in the same union, so having them both unemployed is very costly, say $u_{b,c} = 4$. Any other combination of unemployed workers cost $1$, so the minimum cost assignment has a total cost of $4$, e.g. $(a,x), (c,
y)$.

edit: Whoever wants to downvote: Feel free to do so, but please be so kind to actually comment about **why** you downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Define $w-k$ new tasks to represent idleness.  Now you can use your $c_{ij}$ formalism to model different costs of each worker being idle.

Comment: This is not what I need. I don't have costs for every worker being unemployed but for every **combination** of $w-k$ unemployed workers.

Comment: @choeger Are you saying that you have an **exponentially**-sized unemployment cost vector?  In that case, it takes roughly the same time to try every combination as it does just to read the cost vector, so what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, that vector may be quite large. But the whole point of this exercise is to use this technique in cases where it is actually "small enough". I just want to prove the correctness of the transformation in general.